# createinstallmedia: command not found

Tags: macos

I am trying to create a bootable flash drive that is named Untitled from my MacBook Pro Retina with Yosemite 10.10.

This is what I am getting in Terminal:

```
mbp2013retina:~ chris$ sudo /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Mavericks.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/Untitled --applicationpath /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Mavericks.app --nointeraction
sudo: /Applications/Install OS X Mavericks.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia: command not found
```

Can someone help?

Comment: In my case the `Install macOS *.app` simply did NOT have `Resources` folder, so maybe [see how use Disk Utility to make bootable from `InstallESD.dmg`](https://superuser.com/a/444086/896280) (if you have the same issue, and your `Install macOS *.app` directory contains `InstallESD.dmg` file).

Answer (score 4):

I use following method.

1. Format the USB:

   - Format it, using Disk Utility, as a Mac OS Extended (Journaled) drive, named Yosemite.
2. Next run this in Terminal where you can remove the option `—nointeraction` if you want to get notifications and make decisions yourself about the disk and making the USB installer:

   ```
   sudo /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Yosemite.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/Untitled --applicationpath /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Yosemite.app —nointeraction
   ```

   - Replace Untitled with name of the USB drive (Yosemite)

---

For additional information, see: [Create a bootable installer for OS X](https://support.apple.com/HT201372)

Comment: It is better to use the command without the option ` —nointeraction` because then the user will know what is going to happen and prevent possible complications/damages.

Comment: Make sure you have two hyphen characters in "--nointeraction"

Answer (score 0):

You just remove the space of os name, once you downloaded in Application Path. `Install OS X Yosemite.app to InstallOSXYosemite.app`

```
sudo /Applications/InstallOSXYosemite.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/Untitled --applicationpath /Applications/InstallOSXYosemite.app --nointeraction
```